# Open all generated links in an iframe to open in a new window or tab

Tags: iframe

So I've been given an embed code to display a leader board on my website but if I click on any of the links in the iframe I get a connection refused.

So I need a way that when you click on any of the links they open in a new window or tab.

I've looked everywhere and can't see to find a solution as I don't have control of the domain the links are generated from.

The code I was given was this.

`<iframe src="https://theurl" width="100%" height="500" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>`

Tried looking for a solution but they all seem to be with links that I make.

Please note have very little coding understanding and just starting out.